# VB NET problems with background worker

Tags: vb.net, backgroundworker

While my background worker is doing his job, I want to change a label in main form telling what process is taking in that time.

The app works with some files, so I need to pass the information of the file the app is working on.

My Background Worker

```
    Private Sub BackgroundWorker1_DoWork(sender As Object, e As System.ComponentModel.DoWorkEventArgs) Handles BackgroundWorker1.DoWork
    If (Not System.IO.Directory.Exists(caminho & "\results")) Then
        System.IO.Directory.CreateDirectory(caminho & "\results")
    End If
    For Each folder As String In System.IO.Directory.GetDirectories(caminho)
        Dim split As String() = folder.Split("\")
        Dim parentFolder As String = split(split.Length - 1)
        If (Not System.IO.Directory.Exists(caminho & "\results" & "\" & parentFolder)) Then
            System.IO.Directory.CreateDirectory(caminho & "\results" & "\" & parentFolder)
        End If
        For Each file As String In System.IO.Directory.GetFiles(folder)
            output = file
            'Dim imgFile As System.Drawing.Image = System.Drawing.Image.FromFile(file)
            Dim thumbimage As Bitmap
            Dim originalimage As Bitmap

            Dim width As Integer = TextBox2.Text '# this is the max width of the new image
            Dim height As Integer = TextBox3.Text '# this is the max height of the new image

            originalimage = System.Drawing.Image.FromFile(file)

            thumbimage = New Bitmap(width, height)
            Dim novonome As String = Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(file)

            Dim gr As Graphics = Graphics.FromImage(thumbimage)
            gr.DrawImage(originalimage, 0, 0, width, height)

            thumbimage.Save(caminho & "\results" & "\" & parentFolder & "\" & novonome & ".png", Imaging.ImageFormat.Png)
            thumbimage.Dispose()
            originalimage.Dispose()
        Next
    Next
End Sub
```

My On Progress Change:

```
    Private Sub BackgroundWorker1_ProgressChanged(sender As Object, e As ProgressChangedEventArgs) Handles BackgroundWorker1.ProgressChanged
    Label3.Text = "Working file " & output
End Sub
```

Isn't supposed to change the label3.text in form1 with the file it's working? Basically nothing happens to label3.

My output var is declared under Public Class Form1.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You need to dispose of the `Graphics` object as well to avoid memory leaks. However manually calling `Dispose()` like that isn't safe if an exception is suddenly thrown before that. You ought to wrap both your images an the `Graphics` object in [**`Using` blocks**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/language-reference/statements/using-statement).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Make sure your BackgroundWorker object has `WorkerReportsProgress = True`

You have to call the progress from within your loop:

```
For Each file As String In System.IO.Directory.GetFiles(folder)
  BackgroundWorker1.ReportProgress(0, file)
  ...
```

Then in your Progress event, read the status:

```
Private Sub BackgroundWorker1_ProgressChanged(sender As Object, e As ProgressChangedEventArgs) Handles BackgroundWorker1.ProgressChanged
  If e.UserState IsNot Nothing Then
    Label3.Text = "Working file " & e.UserState.ToString
  End If
End Sub
```

Comment: You probably also need to caution the user that calling ReportProgress() for every single file can be quite troublesome.  Short from the user just not being able to read the very rapidly changing text, enough time should expire so the worker can't firehose the UI thread with too many paint requests and making it burn 100% core.  Easy to do with DateTime.UtcNow, once every 100 msec is plenty good enough.